# Como construir um Objeto com um Array dentro, usando o Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, array, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Olá pessoal preciso construir um `array` da seguinte forma para um plugin:

```
var data = [{
    "label": "Follows",
    "color": "#aad874",
    "data": [
        ["Seg", 50],
        ["Ter", 84],
        ["Qua", 52],
        ["Qui", 88],
        ["Sex", 69],
        ["Sab", 92],
        ["Dom", 58]
    ]
}, {
    "label": "UnFollows",
    "color": "#7dc7df",
    "data": [
        ["Seg", 13],
        ["Ter", 44],
        ["Qua", 44],
        ["Qui", 27],
        ["Sex", 38],
        ["Sab", 11],
        ["Dom", 39]
    ]
}];
```

Já tentei varias coisas como:

```
$staticWeeks = self::statisticstaWeeks();

$staticsDays['Follow']      = [];
$staticsDays['FollowBy']    = [];

if(count($staticWeeks) > 0):
foreach($staticWeeks as $weeks):
array_push($staticsDays['Follow'], $weeks->ins_sta_follow);
array_push($staticsDays['FollowBy'], $weeks->ins_sta_following);
endforeach;
endif;

$staticsDays['Follow'] = $diasFollow = [
    "Seg" => (!empty($staticsDays['Follow'][0]) ? $staticsDays['Follow'][0] : 0), 
    "Ter" => (!empty($staticsDays['Follow'][1]) ? $staticsDays['Follow'][1] : 0), 
    "Qua" => (!empty($staticsDays['Follow'][2]) ? $staticsDays['Follow'][2] : 0),
    "Qui" => (!empty($staticsDays['Follow'][3]) ? $staticsDays['Follow'][3] : 0), 
    "Sex" => (!empty($staticsDays['Follow'][4]) ? $staticsDays['Follow'][4] : 0), 
    "Sab" => (!empty($staticsDays['Follow'][5]) ? $staticsDays['Follow'][5] : 0), 
    "Dom" => (!empty($staticsDays['Follow'][6]) ? $staticsDays['Follow'][6] : 0)];

$staticsDays['FollowBy'] = $diasFollowBy = [
    "Seg" => (!empty($staticsDays['FollowBy'][0]) ? $staticsDays['FollowBy'][0] : 0), 
    "Ter" => (!empty($staticsDays['FollowBy'][1]) ? $staticsDays['FollowBy'][1] : 0), 
    "Qua" => (!empty($staticsDays['FollowBy'][2]) ? $staticsDays['FollowBy'][2] : 0),
    "Qui" => (!empty($staticsDays['FollowBy'][3]) ? $staticsDays['FollowBy'][3] : 0), 
    "Sex" => (!empty($staticsDays['FollowBy'][4]) ? $staticsDays['FollowBy'][4] : 0), 
    "Sab" => (!empty($staticsDays['FollowBy'][5]) ? $staticsDays['FollowBy'][5] : 0), 
    "Dom" => (!empty($staticsDays['FollowBy'][6]) ? $staticsDays['FollowBy'][6] : 0)];

$follow = [(object)[
    "label" => "Seguindo",
    "color" => "#aad874",
    "data"  => $staticsDays['Follow']
]];

$followBy = [(object)[
    "label" => "Seguidores",
    "color" => "#7dc7df",
    "data"  => $staticsDays['FollowBy']
]];

$result = array_merge($follow, $followBy);

return json_encode( $result );
```

E mesmo assim não retorna como eu quero.

Comment: Repara que quando fazer `"Seg" => "qualquercoisa"` isso vai gerar `{"Seg": "qualquercoisa"}` e o que queres é `["seg", "qualquercoisa"]` certo? Assim em vez de objetos tens de criar arrays com `["Seg", (!empty($staticsDays['Follow'][0]) ? $staticsDays['Follow'][0] : 0)]`. Testa isso.

Comment: Uma dica nada a ver, mas evite usar o alias para `array()`.  Exemplo `$array = [ ]`. Pois é compatível somente a partir do PHP 5.4.

Comment: Já tinha tentando isso Daniel Omine, mesmo assim voltava objeto

Comment: @DanielOmine porém laravel só funciona com PhP 5.6 ou superior, então não irá ter nenhum problema